# Analog Clock for WebAssembly in AEC

Tags: datetime, animation, ascii-art, aec

I've ported the [Analog Clock program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244078/analog-clock-in-aec) written in AEC from Linux to WebAssembly. You can see the [live version](https://flatassembler.github.io/analogClock.html).

```
/*
 * This is my attempt to port the Analog Clock in AEC, previously available
 * for Linux and DOS, to WebAssembly.
 */

//Let's import some functions useful for debugging from JavaScript...
Function logString(CharacterPointer str) Which Returns Nothing Is External;
Function logInteger(Integer32 int) Which Returns Nothing Is External;

//Now let's define a character array that will be used both by JS and AEC.
Character output[23 * 80];
Integer32 colors[23 * 80]; //Integer32 can be used as pointer to pointer,
                           //for a lack of a more appropriate type in the
                           //current version of AEC. "colors" will point
                           //to the CSS names of the colors of the specific
                           //characters in "output".

Function getAddressOfOutput() Which Returns CharacterPointer Does
    Return AddressOf(output[0]); //When I didn't implement the "extern"
                                 //keyword into my AEC compiler...
EndFunction

Function getAddressOfColors() Which Returns Integer32Pointer Does
    Return AddressOf(colors[0]); //AEC doesn't currently support
                                 //pointers to pointers, but it's
                                 //trivial to cast this to the
                                 //correct type in JavaScript.
EndFunction

//Now, let's implement some mathematical functions. We can't use JavaScript
//"Math.sin" and similar because they are methods of the global "Math"
//object, and there is, as far as I know, no way to import JavaScript
//objects into WebAssembly (or some language that compiles into it).
//I wonder whether this is what operating system development feels like.
//In the OS development, the only code that's running on a virtual machine
//is your own, and you can only use a debugger running outside of that
//virtual machine. Here, quite some code runs on JavaScript Virtual Machine,
//but the only code I can call is the code I've written myself in my own
//programming language and some debugging functions (logString and logInteger).
Decimal32 PRECISION := 512; //So that we can balance between speed and
                            //precision.
Function ln(Decimal32 x) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    //Natural logarithm is the integral of 1/x from 1 to x, highschool math.
    Decimal32 sum     := 0,
              epsilon := (x - 1) / (5 * PRECISION),
              i       := 1;
    While (epsilon > 0 and i < x) or (epsilon < 0 and i > x) Loop
        sum := sum + epsilon / i;
        i   :=       i + epsilon;
    EndWhile
    Return sum;
EndFunction

Function exp(Decimal32 x) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    //Euler's Algorithm from Mathematics 2...
    Decimal32 i := 0, y := 1, epsilon := x / PRECISION;
    While (epsilon > 0 and i < x) or (epsilon < 0 and i > x) Loop
        y := y + epsilon * y;
        i :=     i + epsilon;
    EndWhile
    Return y;
EndFunction

Function sqrt(Decimal32 x) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    //Binary Search Algorithm...
    Decimal32 max := 80 * 24,
              min :=       0,
              i   := (min + max) / 2;
    While (max - min) > 1 / PRECISION Loop
        If i * i > x Then
            max := i;
        Else
            min := i;
        EndIf
        i := (max + min) / 2;
    EndWhile
    Return i;
EndFunction

Function fmod(Decimal32 a, Decimal32 b) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    Return a - b * Integer32(a / b);
EndFunction

//Now, let's implement trigonometric and cyclometric functions.
Decimal32 oneRadianInDegrees := 180 / pi; //"180/pi" is a compile-time decimal
                                          //constant (since we are assigning an
                                          //initial value to a global variable),
                                          //and, as such, we can use "pi" to
                                          //refer to M_PI from the C library,
                                          //it's available to the compiler.

Function arctan(Decimal32 x) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    //Arcus tangens is equal to the integral of 1/(1+x^2), highschool math.
    Decimal32 sum := 0, epsilon := x / PRECISION, i := 0;
    While i < x Loop
        sum := sum + epsilon / (1 + i * i);
        i   :=                 i + epsilon;
    EndWhile
    Return sum * oneRadianInDegrees;
EndFunction

Function sin(Decimal32 degrees) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    If degrees<0 Then
        Return -sin(-degrees);
    EndIf
    If degrees>90 Then
        Decimal32 sinOfDegreesMinus90 := sin(degrees - 90);
        If fmod(degrees, 360) < 180 Then
            Return sqrt(1 - sinOfDegreesMinus90 * sinOfDegreesMinus90);
        Else
            Return -sqrt(1 - sinOfDegreesMinus90 * sinOfDegreesMinus90);
        EndIf
    EndIf
    /* 
     * Sine and cosine are defined in Mathematics 2 using the system of
     * equations (Cauchy system):
     * 
     * sin(0)=0
     * cos(0)=1
     * sin'(x)=cos(x)
     * cos'(x)=-sin(x)
     * ---------------
     *
     * Let's translate that as literally as possible to the programming
     * language.
     */
    Decimal32 radians := degrees / oneRadianInDegrees,
              tmpsin  := 0,
              tmpcos  := 1,
              epsilon := radians / PRECISION,
              i       := 0;
    While (epsilon>0 and i<radians) or (epsilon<0 and i>radians) Loop
        tmpsin := tmpsin + epsilon * tmpcos;
        tmpcos := tmpcos - epsilon * tmpsin;
        i      :=               i + epsilon;
    EndWhile
    Return tmpsin;
EndFunction

Function arcsin(Decimal32 x) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    Return arctan(x / sqrt(1 - x * x)); //Highschool mathematics.
EndFunction

Function arccos(Decimal32 x) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    Return 90 - arcsin(x); //Basic common sense to somebody who understands
                           //what those terms mean.
EndFunction

Function cos(Decimal32 degrees) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    Return sin(90 - degrees); //Again, basic common sense to somebody who
                              //understands what those terms means.
EndFunction

Function tan(Decimal32 degrees) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    Return sin(degrees) / cos(degrees); //The definition.
EndFunction

Function abs(Decimal32 x) Which Returns Decimal32 Does
    Return x < 0?
              -x
           :
               x;
EndFunction

//Now, let's implement some string manipulation functions. We can't
//call the methods of the JavaScript "String" class here.
Function strlen(CharacterPointer ptr) Which Returns Integer32 Does
    Return ValueAt(ptr) = 0 ?
                                0
                            :
                                1 + strlen(ptr + 1);
EndFunction

Function strcat(CharacterPointer first, CharacterPointer second) Which
    Returns Nothing Does
    first := first + strlen(first);
    While ValueAt(second) Loop
        ValueAt(first) := ValueAt(second);
        first          :=       first + 1;
        second         :=      second + 1;
    EndWhile
    ValueAt(first) := 0;
EndFunction

//And, finally, we can start porting the original AEC Analog Clock,
//which was targeting x86, to WebAssembly.
Function updateClockToTime(Integer32 hour,
                           Integer32 minute,
                           Integer32 second)
    Which Returns Nothing Does
    Integer32 windowWidth  := 80,
              windowHeight := 23,
              i            :=  0;
    CharacterPointer lightGrayColor  := "#EEEEEE";
    CharacterPointer lightGreenColor := "#CCFFCC";
    While i < windowWidth * windowHeight Loop //First, fill the window with 
                                              //spaces and newlines.
        If mod(i, windowWidth) = windowWidth - 1 Then
            output[i] := '\n';
        Else
            output[i] := ' ';
        EndIf
        colors[i] := lightGrayColor;
        i         :=          i + 1;
    EndWhile
    Integer32 centerX     :=     windowWidth / 2,
              centerY     :=    windowHeight / 2,
              clockRadius := (centerX < centerY)?
                                centerX - 1
                             :
                                centerY - 1;
    i := 0;
    While i < windowWidth * windowHeight Loop //Next, draw the circle which
                                              //represents the clock
        Integer32 y :=     i / windowWidth,
                  x := mod(i, windowWidth);
        Decimal32 distance := sqrt((x - centerX) * (x - centerX) +
                                   (y-centerY) * (y-centerY)); //Pythagorean
                                                               //Theorem.
        If abs(distance - clockRadius) < 3. / 4 Then
            output[i] := '*';
            colors[i] := lightGreenColor;
        EndIf
        i := i + 1;
    EndWhile
    CharacterPointer redColor := "#FFAAAA";
    //Label "12"...
    output[(centerY - clockRadius + 1) * windowWidth + centerX]     := '1';
    output[(centerY - clockRadius + 1) * windowWidth + centerX + 1] := '2';
    colors[(centerY - clockRadius + 1) * windowWidth + centerX]     :=
    colors[(centerY - clockRadius + 1) * windowWidth + centerX + 1] := redColor;
    //Label "6"...
    output[(centerY + clockRadius - 1) * windowWidth + centerX]     := '6';
    colors[(centerY + clockRadius - 1) * windowWidth + centerX]     := redColor;
    //Label "3"...
    output[centerY * windowWidth + centerX + clockRadius - 1]       := '3';
    colors[centerY * windowWidth + centerX + clockRadius - 1]       := redColor;
    //Label "9"...
    output[centerY * windowWidth + centerX - clockRadius + 1]       := '9';
    colors[centerY * windowWidth + centerX - clockRadius + 1]       := redColor;
    //Label "1"...
    Integer32 y := centerY - (clockRadius - 1) * cos(360. / 12);
    output[y * windowWidth + centerX + sin(360./12) * (clockRadius - 1)]
          := '1';
    colors[y * windowWidth + centerX + sin(360./12) * (clockRadius - 1)]
          := redColor;
    //Label "2"...
    y := centerY - (clockRadius - 1.5) * cos(2 * 360. / 12);
    output[y * windowWidth  + centerX +
           sin(2 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1.5)] := '2';
    colors[y * windowWidth  + centerX +
           sin(2 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1.5)] := redColor;
    //Label "4"...
    y := centerY - (clockRadius - 1) * cos(4 * 360. / 12);
    output[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(4 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1) + 1] := '4';
    colors[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(4 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1) + 1] := redColor;
    //Label "5"...
    y := centerY - (clockRadius - 1) * cos(5 * 360. / 12);
    output[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(5 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1) + 1] := '5';
    colors[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(5 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1) + 1] := redColor;
    //Label "7"...
    y := centerY - (clockRadius - 1) * cos(7 * 360. / 12);
    output[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(7 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1)] := '7';
    colors[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(7 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1)] := redColor;
    //Label "8"...
    y := centerY - (clockRadius - 1) * cos(8 * 360. / 12);
    output[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(8 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1)] := '8';
    colors[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(8 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1)] := redColor;
    //Label "10"...
    y := centerY - (clockRadius - 1.5) * cos(10 * 360. / 12);
    output[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(10 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1.5) + 1] := '1';
    output[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(10 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1.5) + 2] := '0';
    colors[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(10 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1.5) + 1] :=
    colors[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(10 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1.5) + 2] := redColor;
    //Label "11"...
    y := centerY - (clockRadius - 1.5) * cos(11 * 360. / 12);
    output[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(11 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1.5) + 1] :=
    output[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(11 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1.5) + 2] := '1';
    colors[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(11 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1.5) + 1] :=
    colors[y * windowWidth + centerX +
           sin(11 * 360. / 12) * (clockRadius - 1.5) + 2] := redColor;
    Integer32 j := 0;
    Decimal32 angle;
    CharacterPointer blueColor   := "#AAAAFF";
    CharacterPointer yellowColor := "#FFFFAA";
    While j < 3 Loop
        CharacterPointer currentColor;
        If j = 0 Then
            angle := fmod(hour + minute / 60., 12) * (360. / 12);
            currentColor := redColor;
        ElseIf j = 1 Then
            angle := minute * (360. / 60);
            currentColor := yellowColor;
        Else
            angle := second * (360 / 60);
            currentColor := blueColor;
        EndIf
        Decimal32 endOfTheHandX := centerX + sin(angle) *
                                   clockRadius /
                                   (j = 0 ? 2. : j = 1 ? 3. / 2 : 4. / 3),
                  endOfTheHandY := centerY - cos(angle) *
                                   clockRadius /
                                   (j = 0 ? 2. : j = 1 ? 3. / 2 : 4. / 3),
                  coefficientOfTheDirection := (endOfTheHandY - centerY) /
                                               (
                                               abs(endOfTheHandX - centerX) = 0?
                                               //Protect ourselves from
                                               //dividing by 0.
                                                   1. / 100
                                               :
                                                   endOfTheHandX - centerX
                                               );
        logString("Drawing line between (");
        logInteger(centerX);
        logString(",");
        logInteger(centerY);
        logString(") and (");
        logInteger(endOfTheHandX);
        logString(",");
        logInteger(endOfTheHandY);
        logString(").\n");
        i := 0;
        While i < windowWidth * windowHeight Loop
            Decimal32 lowerBoundX := endOfTheHandX < centerX ?
                                        endOfTheHandX
                                     :
                                        Decimal32(centerX),
                      upperBoundX := endOfTheHandX > centerX ?
                                        endOfTheHandX
                                     :
                                        Decimal32(centerX),
                      lowerBoundY := endOfTheHandY < centerY ?
                                        endOfTheHandY
                                     :
                                        centerY,
                      upperBoundY := endOfTheHandY > centerY ?
                                        endOfTheHandY
                                     :
                                        centerY;
            y := i / windowWidth;
            Integer32 x := mod(i, windowWidth), isXWithinBounds;
            isXWithinBounds := (x > lowerBoundX or x = lowerBoundX)
                               and (x < upperBoundX or x = upperBoundX);
            Integer32 isYWithinBounds;
            isYWithinBounds := (y > lowerBoundY or y = lowerBoundY)
                               and (y < upperBoundY or y = upperBoundY);
            If isXWithinBounds and isYWithinBounds Then
                Decimal32 expectedX, expectedY;
                expectedY := (x - centerX) * coefficientOfTheDirection
                             + centerY;
                expectedX := (y - centerY) * (1/coefficientOfTheDirection)
                             + centerX;
                If coefficientOfTheDirection=1./0 Then
                    expectedY := 1000; //Bigger than any possible value.
                EndIf
                If coefficientOfTheDirection=0 Then
                    expectedX := 1000; //Again, bigger than any possible.
                EndIf
                logString("The point (");
                logInteger(x);
                logString(",");
                logInteger(y);
                logString(") is within bounds, expectedY is ");
                logInteger(expectedY);
                logString(" and expectedX is ");
                logInteger(expectedX);
                logString(".\n");
                Character currentSign := j = 0 ?
                                             'h'
                                         : j = 1 ?
                                             'm'
                                         :
                                             's';
                If (abs(upperBoundX - lowerBoundX) < 1 + 1 / PRECISION or
                    abs(upperBoundY - lowerBoundY) < 1 + 1 / PRECISION)
                   and output[i] = ' ' Then
                    output[i] :=  currentSign;
                    colors[i] := currentColor;
                EndIf
                If (abs(expectedX - x) < 3./4 or abs(expectedY - y) < 3./4)
                   and output[i] = ' ' Then
                    output[i] :=  currentSign;
                    colors[i] := currentColor;
                EndIf
            EndIf
            i := i + 1;
        EndWhile
        j := j + 1;
    EndWhile
    //Let's draw some ornaments.
    CharacterPointer darkGreenColor := "#AAFFAA";
    i := 0;
    While i < windowWidth * windowHeight Loop
        y := i / windowWidth;
        Integer32 x := mod(i, windowWidth);
        If abs(windowHeight - 2 * ln(1 + abs((x - centerX) / 2.)) - y)
            < 1 - abs(x - centerX) / (centerX * 95./112)
            and x > 1./2 * centerX and x < 3./2 * centerX
            and output[i] = ' ' Then //The logarithmic curve looks somewhat
                                     //like a lemma of a flower.
            output[i] :=            'x';
            colors[i] := darkGreenColor;
        EndIf
        i := i + 1;
    EndWhile
    //Let's try to make it look like the bottom of the lemma isn't floating
    //in the air.
    j := 0;
    While j < 3 Loop
        i := windowWidth * (windowHeight - 1);//So, move to the beginning of
                                              //the last line.
        While i < windowWidth * windowHeight Loop
            If j < 2 and (output[i - windowWidth] = 'x' and
                (output[i + 1] = 'x' or output[i - 1] = 'x')) Then
                output[i] :=            'x';
                colors[i] := darkGreenColor;
            ElseIf j=2 and (output[i + 1]=' ' and
                output[i - windowWidth] = 'x') Then
                output[i] := ' ';
            EndIf
            i := i + 1;
        EndWhile
        j := j + 1;
    EndWhile
    //The digital clock in the corner...
    output[windowWidth * windowHeight - 2] := '0' + mod(second, 10);
    output[windowWidth * windowHeight - 3] := '0' + second / 10;
    colors[windowWidth * windowHeight - 2] :=
        colors[windowWidth * windowHeight - 3] := blueColor;
    output[windowWidth * windowHeight - 4] := ':';
    output[windowWidth * windowHeight - 5] := '0' + mod(minute, 10);
    output[windowWidth * windowHeight - 6] := '0' + minute / 10;
    colors[windowWidth * windowHeight - 5] :=
        colors[windowWidth * windowHeight - 6] := yellowColor;
    output[windowWidth * windowHeight - 7] := ':';
    output[windowWidth * windowHeight - 8] := '0' + mod(hour,10);
    output[windowWidth * windowHeight - 9] := '0' + hour / 10;
    colors[windowWidth * windowHeight - 8] :=
        colors[windowWidth * windowHeight - 9] := redColor;
    //My signature...
    Character signature[100] := {0};
    CharacterPointer signature := AddressOf(signature[0]);
    //AEC, unlike C, always makes a clear distinction between
    //arrays and pointers.
    logString("Empty signature has length of: ");
    logInteger(strlen(signature));
    logString("\n");
    strcat(signature, " Analog Clock for WebAssembly\n");
    logString("The first row of the signature has length of: ");
    logInteger(strlen(signature));
    logString("\n");
    strcat(signature, " Made in AEC by\n");
    logString("The first two rows of signature have length: ");
    logInteger(strlen(signature));
    logString("\n");
    strcat(signature, " Teo Samarzija");
    logString("Signature has length of: ");
    logInteger(strlen(signature));
    logString(" \n\n"); //Let's mark the last log of this function like this.
    i := windowWidth * (windowHeight - 3);
    j := 0;
    CharacterPointer modraColor := "#AAFFFF"; //Sorry, I don't know how
                                              //to say "modra" in English,
                                              //and I am not wasting my time
                                              //looking that up.
    While not(signature[j] = 0) Loop
        If signature[j] = '\n' Then
            i := (i / windowWidth + 1) * windowWidth;
        ElseIf not(signature[j] = 0) Then
            output[i] := signature[j];
            colors[i] :=   modraColor;
            i         :=        i + 1;
        Else
            output[i] := ' ';
        EndIf
        j := j + 1;
    EndWhile
EndFunction
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: what is aec?  Looking at your linked program, it looks like you haven't read the comments posted which explain why your question wasn't answered